# Expressing bacterial proteins in mammalian cells

Tags: molecular-biology, protein-expression

Does anyone have experience/knowledge of expressing bacterial (or other microbial) proteins in mammalian cells? I am interested in this for a project where we are trying to introduce a new enzymatic activity in human cells. I have been looking for examples in the literature, but haven't found anything so far.

I can imagine that various problems might arise. Presumably transcription and translation should not be a problem; but I can imagine the protein may not get sorted/localized properly, or might not be properly degraded and so could  accumulate to toxic levels ...  or what not.

Any advice or pointers to literature would be much appreciated!